# Function returning function object rather than prototype value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the value of `arr[0]`, but when I attempt to do just that I end up receiving the `test` function object.  Here is an example:

```
function test() {
    if (!(this instanceof test)) return new test();
    console.log(this.arr[0]); //Logs "0"
    console.log(typeof this.arr[0]) //Logs "number"
    return this.arr[0];
}

test.prototype.arr = [0];

var t = test();
console.log(t); //Logs test function object
console.log(typeof t); //Logs "object"
```

So, can anyone explain

1. Why it is returning an object rather than the array value
2. If there is a way to return the array value

Thanks :)

--edit--

> Why are you doing this? if (!(this instanceof test)) return new test();

It's a puzzle.  I have to return the *nth* smallest hamming number.  I'm not really good at math, so instead of trying to find some complex equation to do just that, I'm generating a list of hamming numbers in order and pushing them to the prototype array.

The function is run over 1k times, and generally in order.  What I'm trying to get at here is to only have to calculate any given hamming number once.  My actual function checks the length of the prototype array, and if the nth number is already present, returns that value rather than recalculating from 0 again.

I may yet go about it a different way, but I'm perplexed as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `if (!(this instanceof test)) return new test();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning a new test, just like you asked it to do in the first line of the function.

Since the first time you call it, it is not an instance of test (since it was invoked as a regular function instead of a constructor), it returns "new test()", which invokes test as a constructor.  In JavaScript, you cannot return arbitrary values from a constructor (when invoked with "new") -- it always returns the created object.

Example:

```
function Foobar() { return 2 }

console.log(typeof Foobar()); // "number"
console.log(typeof new Foobar()); // "object"
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I had assumed it would run the constructor and return whatever value the constructor did, since it was defined.

Comment: Understandably confusing.  You can think of it as the "new" operator that actually returns the value in that case, not the function.

Comment: @Eclecticist—when called as a constructor, a function must return an object. Since the last line of your constructor returns `this.arr[0]`, which is a primitive, the *this* object (a new instance of *test*) is returned instead (per the [*`[[Construct]]`*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) internal method). If you initialise *arr* as say `test.prototype.arr = [{}];` then that empty object would be returned instead.